How to adjust text based on vw and vh in tailwind using React?
I use React + Tailwind. My goal is to have two rectangles over each other with text. The top box text is to the left, the bottom box text is to the right. Based on adjusting the window with and height, the font shall adjust so that it always fills out the box with the same proportions, no matter the window size. Also, looking at the attached screenshot: the positions shall stay the same:

the bottom text always shall start where the t of 'first' is
the space between the first and second sentence shall stay the same.

The code I have now increases the space between the sentences and their position.
const Hero = ({ ...props }: HeroProps): JSX.Element => {
  const textStyle = {
    fontSize: `8vw`
  };
    return (
        <div className='h-2/5 w-full'>
          <div className="w-5/6 h-1/2 bg-red-500 flex items-center">
            <h1 className="font-impact whitespace-nowrap w-full h-full" style={textStyle}>The first sentence</h1> 
          </div>
          <div className="w-5/6 h-1/2 bg-blue-500 ml-auto flex items-center">
           <h1 className="font-impact text-right whitespace-nowrap w-full h-full" style={textStyle}>The second sentence</h1>
           </div>
        </div>
  );
};

For context, I want to have this implemented in the first part of my page, hence
<div className='h-2/5 w-full'>

Screenshot of how it currently is but doesn't adjust correctly: 
Any help is appreciated.

Use vw arbitrary values for text size.
<div class="h-2/5 w-full">
  <div class="flex h-1/2 w-5/6 items-center bg-red-500">
    <h1 class="font-impact h-full w-full whitespace-nowrap text-[5vw]" style="{textStyle}">The first sentence</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="ml-auto flex h-1/2 w-5/6 items-center bg-blue-500">
    <h1 class="font-impact h-full w-full whitespace-nowrap text-right  text-[5vw]" style="{textStyle}">The second sentence</h1>
  </div>
</div>

https://play.tailwindcss.com/EogMqGkKK2
